# Como utilizar imagem de perfil no flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Tenho um card representado por mostrar a foto do usuário + o nome do mesmo, quando busco uma imagem local ela carrega a imagem normalmente, porém quando preciso carregar essa imagem através de um link da minha api ela não carrega.

Imagem de ilustração
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```
return ListView(
          children: <Widget>[

            _qrCodeWidget(this.bytes, context),

            Container(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  SlimyCard(
              color: Color(0xffccffcc),
              topCardWidget: topCardWidget((snapshot.data)
                ? 'imagens/${gv.foto}'
                : ''), 

            ),
                ],
              ),

            ),
          ],
        );
```

O local correto que gostaria de colocar é dentro de `topCardWidget: topCardWidget((snapshot.data)
                    ? 'imagens/${gv.foto}'
                    : ''),`

Tem outra maneira de colocar essa imagem, porém não me atendeu por exemplo.
Nesse código acima ele chama o método **topCardWidget** dentro dele temos o seguinte código:

```
 Widget topCardWidget(String imagePath) {

return Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      child: Image.network('https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fstorage.googleapis.com%2Fgweb-uniblog-publish-prod%2Fimages%2FAndroid_symbol_green_2.max-1500x1500.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.blog.google%2Fproducts%2Fandroid%2F&docid=SDYhQ-MI_6500M&tbnid=rL2RK3y7U-kTxM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwiY0p7Ey5TmAhXkIbkGHYlbBtMQMwh3KAAwAA..i&w=1500&h=803&bih=635&biw=1024&q=android&ved=0ahUKEwiY0p7Ey5TmAhXkIbkGHYlbBtMQMwh3KAAwAA&iact=mrc&uact=8'),
      height: 70,
      width: 70,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
        image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage(imagePath)),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
            blurRadius: 20,
            spreadRadius: 1,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    SizedBox(height: 15),
    Text(
      '${gv.nome}',
      style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff1e1e1e), fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
    ),
    SizedBox(height: 15),
    Text(
      'Para escanear precione o ícone da câmera!',
      style: TextStyle(
          color: Color(0xff1e1e1e),
          fontSize: 15,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
    ),
    SizedBox(height: 10),
  ],
);
 }
```

na linha `child: Image.network('https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fstorage.googleapis.com%2Fgweb-uniblog-publish-prod%2Fimages%2FAndroid_symbol_green_2.max-1500x1500.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.blog.google%2Fproducts%2Fandroid%2F&docid=SDYhQ-MI_6500M&tbnid=rL2RK3y7U-kTxM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwiY0p7Ey5TmAhXkIbkGHYlbBtMQMwh3KAAwAA..i&w=1500&h=803&bih=635&biw=1024&q=android&ved=0ahUKEwiY0p7Ey5TmAhXkIbkGHYlbBtMQMwh3KAAwAA&iact=mrc&uact=8'),` consigo colocar qualquer link, porém ele perde a formatação da imagem com bordas arredondadas e deixa apenas quadrada.

Comment: Opa boa tarde, eu não vou postar como resposta por que não to no meu pc em casa pra te mostrar um exemplo, mas eu fiz da seguinte forma, peguei a imagem e passei ela pra um BoxDecoration dentro do container mas utilizando a propriedade decoration do próprio Container. Experimenta fazer isso e me diz se deu certo, caso você não consiga, assim que eu chegar em casa hoje eu posto um exemplo aqui pra ti de como ficou meu código.

Comment: Matheus,

Não consegui reproduzir no meu código, quando tiver um tempo pode me apresentar um modelo?

Valeu :)

Comment: Opa Thiago, sim consigo assim que eu chegar eu casa eu monto um exemplo de como fiz, agora estou no trabalho hehe mas assim que chegar eu já monto e posto como resposta aqui pra ti dai, vlww

Comment: opa Thiago blz, tava vendo o tópico e notei um errinho, não sei se já notou, mas precione está escrito errado no seu app :)

Comment: Opa já alterei isso rs, já mudei algumas coisas valeu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opa Thiago boa noite, como prometido aqui está um exemplo de como eu utilizei o BoxDecoration pra deixar as imagens com bordas arredondadas:

Aqui é um exemplo de um retângulo com bordas arredondadas:

```
Decoration boxDecorationRetangularImagem({double raioBorda, String linkImage}) {
  return new BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.grey[300],
    shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(raioBorda),
    image: new DecorationImage(image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(linkImage), fit: BoxFit.fill),
  );
}
```

E aqui um exemplo de um circulo com imagem estilo a do facebook:

```
Decoration boxDecorationCircularImagem({String linkImage}) {
  return new BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.white,
    shape: BoxShape.circle,
    image: new DecorationImage(image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(linkImage), fit: BoxFit.fill),
  );
}
```

Comment: Show de bola Matheus, muito obrigado mesmo pela resposta!

Comment: Show fico feliz que deu certo, funcionou?

Comment: Perfeitamente!
Valeu mesmo cara :)

Comment: Show de bola :D feliz que funcionou, uma boa noite e bons estudos

Comment: Valeu obrigado pela força Matheus.